# Spark WebUI Application application_xyz not found

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

When I am trying to open the history of any of the spark job I am facing this issue "Application_id: Application application_xyz not found",

NOTE:
previously I figured out this as one of the spark history folder was full so this error occurred but now I don't remember how to do it?
Any Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tobe able to access Spark UI after application has finished you need a separate history server.

Please start the server

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

and follow [configuration notes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

Comment: My problem was resolved when I cleaned this directory - /user/spark/applicationHistory